# Binding Data to gridView in Windows RT

Tags: c#, windows, data-binding, windows-store-apps

I am taking movie information from internet, and I put them in a class. The class contains title, name, description, and a picture from the movie. I took the data as Json response, I parsed correctly, so to obtain List ( a list of movies). Now I want to bind my data to some gridview, let's say to the grid app template given in the Visual Studio, but I am not succeding till now.
Does anybody have a sugestion, how to accomplish this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the quick starts on this topic.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh758318(v=win.10).aspx

this sample in particular shows you how to use gridview and semantic zoom.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/GroupedGridView-77c59e8e/view/SourceCode

All you need to do is set the binding correctly and then set the list as ItemSource